Apim json request payload validation
I need to validate a JSON schema for a POST operation in Apim, but my schema varies depending on the request type. Additionally, the JSON payload I’m working with is quite extensive (around 1000 lines long). What are the best practices  for efficiently handling schema validation in this scenario?"
I did tried to define the schema but it’s become to long and complex, so I need an expert advice what should I do?


Primarily, add your JSON schema in Schemas blade of APIM.



I have used below schema for testing purpose.

{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "City": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Name",
    "City"
  ]
}


Then, I have added the given policy.

<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="128" size-exceeded-action="ignore" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
            <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="{Your Schema Id}" />
        </validate-content>
    </inbound>
</policies>


I am trying to pass incorrect JSON schema in the request body and getting expected response.



